# looping Q&A IBM watson dialogue?

Tags: python-2.7, watson-conversation

i'm trying to loop this back again instead of ending, so it lets you send another question to watson conversation after the first reply from watson. However I'm a complete newbie at this and finding it difficult so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import json
import watson_developer_cloud

conversation = watson_developer_cloud.ConversationV1(username='', password='', version='2018-03-16')
question = raw_input("what is youre question?\n")
response = conversation.message( workspace_id='*', input={ 'text': question }) 
print('\n'.join(response['output']['text']))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to send the `context` from your first message to your next *post* message, and you will continue the conversation flow. Summary,  you need to include `context object` from the previous response. The main issue is with not maintaining the *context object*.

@Simon O'Doherty did one example of how to do that using Python, check all code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46220946/7133482):

```
result = '\n'.join(response['output']['text'])
context = response['context']

return result
```

Then:

```
response = test('I want to make a reservation')
print(response)
response = test('tomorrow')
print(response)
```

- Take a look at the [Official example](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/develop/examples/conversation_v1.py) for use Watson Conversation from Watson Developer Cloud:
- See more about using Conversation within Official [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/python.html?python#message) - Python.